# Describe me how in this code works Symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript

I am currently reading Eloquent Javascript.And I can not understand this part.

I do not understand Symbol.iterator part.Can  you explain me how it works.Thanks

```
class MatrixIterator {
  constructor(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  }
  next() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {
      done: true
    };
    let value = {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y,
      value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)
    };
    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return {
      value,
      done: false
    };
  }
}



Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return new MatrixIterator(this);
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Answer (score 3):

`Symbol.iterator` is a [*well-known symbol*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#table-1) (which just means it's defined in the spec and available as a property of `Symbol`) that's the key for the method that JavaScript looks for when it needs to get an *iterator* from an object. Iterators are used by `for-of`, `...` (on arrays), and such to loop through the contents of an object.

For instance, in this code:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
for (const value of a) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

the JavaScript engine calls the `[Symbol.iterator]` method on `a` to get the iterator to use for the `for-of` loop.

Here's that same example (roughly) using the iterator directly rather than letting `for-of` handle it for us:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
// Get the iterator
const it = a[Symbol.iterator]();
// Get the first result object from it
let result = it.next();
// While the result object doesn't have done = true...
while (!result.done) {
    // Get and show this iteration's value
    const value = result.value;
    console.log(value);
    
    // Get the next result
    result = it.next();
}
```

The great thing about iterators, and having a common defined way to get the iterator for an object, is that it makes things like `for-of` possible regardless of what the object is that's being iterated. Strings are iterable, for instance (you get one character at a time). Maps are iterable (each value you get is a `[key, value]` array). Etc. The object defines both *how* it's iterated and what values it provides during iteration. You could write a simple linked list class and make it iterable, and code using it wouldn't care that it was a linked list instead of an array or whatever.

With that context, this code:

```
Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return new MatrixIterator(this);
};
```

creates that method on the prototype that will be assigned to objects created via `new Matrix` so that calling it returns a new `MatrixIterator` for the matrix instance it was called on.

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

Comment: So when we creating new instance with MatrixIterator matrix becomes this?

Comment: @HrantBaloyan - Normally, yes, because `obj[propertyKey]()` is just like `obj.method()` (if `propertyKey` is `"method"`), so when you make a call in that form, `this` is set to `obj` during the method call. So if you have `const m = new Matrix(/*...*/);`, then in the normal case when `m[Symbol.iterator]()` is called, `this` will be `m` within the call. That method then passes it in as an argument to `new MatrixIterator`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nice description of the `Symbol.iterator`, +1. Also, could you please provide an example of how this could be used on a development routine? Like, using `Symbol.iterator` trough a `while` loop was one example, but what's the benefit of using `Symbol.iterator`? It's still not clear to me:(

Comment: @k3llydev - I've added a bit after the second code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for giving your free time us.